# PHP include prevent having to back track directory

Tags: php, include, directory

I've been using this way for my site for awhile, but now it's just getting to large for me to continue doing this as I have in the past. I am completely recoding it so I want to fix this issue up front.

I have a filed called "includes.php" in the root of the directory, and I need to include this on every single page I have because this file contains things such as a php page for function, the database connection, and whatever else I may need.

right now if I have a directory as such: ajax/load/comment.php

on comment.php I will have to at the top of the page have:

```
<?php
     include("../../includes.php");
?>
```

There must be something I can use in place so it always goes to the root when looking for files.

Answer (score 2):

This should work: (no matter how deep the path is)

```
<?php
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute paths as well. For example:

```
include ('C:/Work/Webroot/store/lib/includes.php');
```

Even better would be to define the base folder in your config file and then use that.

```
define('SITE_ROOT', 'C:/Work/Webroot/store/')
```

and in your php files

```
include(SITE_ROOT.'lib/includes.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You better should use a central point, where you include all necessary files.

At one point in your project it gets REALLY messy, and you have to think of all the possibilities where you included that one file.

An autoloader helps to deal with these problems in larger projects. PHP itself ships some [basic autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) routines.